# Adding background image which should fill page

Tags: html, css

I'm using the following code to show a background image on my page:

```css
#bg-pic {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

#bg-pic > img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-pic">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg" />
</div>
```

This works fine once the ratio of the browser window is wide enough. But in case I have a very small window I want the picture still to cover the page so instead of `width: 100%;` `height: 100%;` would be correct. How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** Since the provided answer don't solve my actual problem let's describe it using an example:

- Let's assume my picture has dimensions 100x100 and my browser window has dimensions 200x100. Then only the upper 100 pixels are filled with the picture. What I want is that the whole browser window is filled by zooming into the picture (of course then the area on the right and on the left of the picture which corresponds to the right 25 and left 25 pixels of the picture is omitted).

Comment: style properties of img tag should be added with height:100vh ,This should solve your problem immediately. you cannot put height:100% unless you have a static height for your outer div or parent div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [background](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property instead of an [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) element.

**Demo:**

```
body {
  background: url('image.jpg') center center / cover;
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t2ucjhw/)**

**In your case:**

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url('bg.jpg') center center / cover;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't set the width or height to 100%. I only see a small section of the image but I want to see full width or full height (according to the ration of the browser window).

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain, isn't the demo in jsFiddle what you need?

Comment: Almost. I want the image top edge to align with the browser window.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want ? A picture, or something else.

Comment: If you want the top edge of the image to align with the top edge of the container, use `background: url("image.jpg") top / cover;`.

Comment: @Tigran I guess that's the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the object-fit and object-position properties on the image tag.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/MathiasaurusRex/pen/BOPmPQ)

```
#bg-pic{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.18;
    z-index: -1; 
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}


#bg-pic img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You can read more about object-fit at CSS-Tricks : https://css-tricks.com/on-object-fit-and-object-position/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you make the top edge of the image align with the browser windows like my initial example would do it?

Comment: Change #bg-pic img object-position: 50% 50% to object-position: 50% 0%;

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `height:100vh;` in your img style tag,
You **can't** use `height:100%` because it won't be applied unless you have specified static height to parent `div`.
Always a better option to go for `vh` dimension.

```css
#bg-pic {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-pic">

<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg" style="width:100%; height:100vh; display: block;"/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body { background-image:url("../images/bg.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: 100% 100%; }
```

Try this

Comment: This doesn't set the width or height to 100%.

Comment: Try this body {
    background-image:url("../images/myImage.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
html {
    height: 100%
}

Comment: Your correction doesn't work the way it is supposed. It doesn't keep the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try flexbox like this:

```css
#bg-pic {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="bg-pic"><img src="https://picsum.photos/800/800?image=1069" style="" /></div>
```

Comment: Quite what I want but one main problem still: When the resolution of the original picture is bigger than the browser window only a part of the original picture is shown. But I want to get the picture scaled such that either the width or the height is 100%.
One minor this is that in case we have height 100% I want the left-right-alignment of the picture to be centered. But it's my own fault that you didn't do that since I didn't state that. This can simply be done by removing "left: 0;".

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain no need to remove left:0 :) it's actually centred ... when the image is height:100% it will overlfow equally on both side and it will be centred due to flexbox properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its cross browser compatible:

```
div {
    position:relative;
}
img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

This assumes you have given a size to the div.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for `background-size: contain`. Paired with `height: 100vh` should give you desired effect.

If you need the image centered horizontally you can add `background-position: 50% 0%` or `background-position: center;` for both horizontal and vertical centering.

```css
#container-with-background {
 background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: contain;
 height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container-with-background">
 </div>
```

If you need your images to be inside your `<img>` tags you can achieve the same effect with `max-width: 100%` and `max-height: 100%` on the `<img>` tag, and fixed height on the container - `height: 500px` for example. Setting the height to `100vh` will make it fullscreen.

```css
#container {
 height: 100vh; /* Can be set to fixed value if needed */
}
img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259915/pexels-photo-259915.jpeg">
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added an example of what goes wrong in your code to my original question.

Comment: I've just read your edit and I see my answer is not what you're looking for, but I'm not entirely sure why [@MathiasRechtzigel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175425/mathias-rechtzigel) `object-fit: cover` answer won't work for you ? Can you describe what exactly is missing in his example?